# Ubuntu 23.04 logs me out arbitrarily while going to sleep mode

Tags: suspend, logout, automatic

I upgraded my desktop to Ubuntu 23.04 a few days ago. Since then I've noticed that sometimes i get logged out when the system goes into sleep mode after 15 minutes of inactivity.

I searched askubuntu and elsewhere for solutions but didn't find any.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Open `Settings` -> `Privacy` -> `Screen` and disable `Automatic Screen Lock`.

[image: Screen Shot]

Read more at https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/privacy-screen-lock.html

Comment: Thanks. But, this doesn't answer my question. I know how to put it n sleep mode; that is not the problem. When my desktop goes into sleep mode, sometimes i get logged out in 23.04; this wasn't the case until now.

Comment: this actually worked for me after 23.10 upgrade, why would "Automatic Screen Lock" mean log the user out? (closing all applications), that doc explicitly says otherwise:

"_When your screen is locked, your applications and system processes will continue to run, but you will need to enter your password to begin using them again._"